# Local fonts only doesn't display on iPhone and my coworkers Mac

Tags: html, fonts, local

So as the gdpr is active since the 25th of may we are setting up our customers websites to be legal. And since google fonts are no longer legal in Europe we had to get rid of them and use local fonts. Now we have the problem that on one website the fonts don't load on iOS 11. Also the fonts don't load on my co workers mac ( the same as mine ). The website only displays content in the wordpress default font ( Times New Roman i think ) .

I used the same fonts and method on other websites, where it works just fine.

Did some one of you guys already had the same problem? Please help me.

Comment: Try using [web safe fonts](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp)...

Comment: Yeah i would so, but the website is already live and it's a complicate customer...